# Reversing an old file format Inbox X

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, medical

I’m trying to reverse engineer an old medical imaging format called Stentor for interoperability. It was designed by a company of the same name who was subsequently bought by Phillips. But Phillips has forgotten how to read Stentor files. I have a windows program which exports JPEG from Stentor files but it’s closed source. I’d like to automate this process in order to tackle hundreds of files in this format.

The program is late-1990s Win32 or MFC executeable. It runs next to an ActiveX (.ocx) file which I’ve been able to interop with, but that file doesn’t contain the export method. I'm looking for suggestions on how to dissemble the binary in order to unearth the algorithm used to convert Stentor to JPEG. I looked through the Stentor files in hex editor and didn’t find any evidence of JPEG (although hints on finding that would be appreciated too), so I think that the program has a couple of tricks up its sleeve.

Thanks in advance.

Kyle

Comment: Hello Kyle, have you reached any solution for this issue, cuz currently I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Few programmers implement complex routines such as image recoding themselves. Instead they tend to license libraries that do that. A very smart way to start would be searching for text strings and see if you can discover the libraries they use. This will subsequently give you a lot of insight into how the data is encoded.

Another good strategy would be to build a program that simply runs the GUI of your export program by sending mouse and keyboard events directly to it. Let this run a few days to complete your export. Reverse engineering the file format is going to be slow and expensive so for a 1 time gig it's probably not worthwhile.